# Translate Postgre SQL code to Java in @Query

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I trying to use `@Query` followed by SQL commands in Java Spring Boot to get data from Postgre SQL database.

My code in Postgre SQL includes something like `… AND x.maturity_date < date(’2022-10-10’) + interval ‘1 day’`. The code works in Postgre SQL.

I translated this SQL Code to Java:
`… AND x.maturityDate < date(:asOf) + interval ‘1 day’`
Where `asOf` is actually a variable in the Java function (in SQL I was using `2022-10-10` as the `asOf` variable.

However, there is an error, which shows this is not how it's supposed to be done.

May I ask if this is the correct way to translate this Postgre SQL code to Java ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is "Java" to you in this context? JPQL? What does Spring have to do with this? Spring's `@Qualifier` is not for queries. You should share some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the question is now solved, it's because we just need to use  `AND x.maturityDate < date(:asOf) + ‘1 day’`